# Systemback 1.9.4 - Errno: 22 during system copy

Tags: 20.04, copy, systemback

Copying my system (included user data copy ) to internal HD, systemback stopped with error 22 and aborted the copy.

[image]

Tried to trace with  **DBGLEV=3 systemback-sustart** having the following result:

```
p_metheny99@jarvis:~$ DBGLEV=3 systemback-sustart
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'

 Systemback

 Version: 1.9.4_05.02.2020_Qt5.12.8_GCC9.3.0_amd64
 Compilation date and time: Apr 15 2018 12:44:46
 Installed files: /etc/xdg/autostart/sbschedule-kde.desktop
                  /etc/xdg/autostart/sbschedule.desktop
                  /usr/bin/systemback
                  /usr/bin/systemback-cli
                  /usr/bin/systemback-sustart
                  /usr/lib/systemback/libsystemback.so
                  /usr/lib/systemback/libsystemback.so.1
                  /usr/lib/systemback/libsystemback.so.1.0
                  /usr/lib/systemback/libsystemback.so.1.0.0
                  /usr/lib/systemback/sbscheduler
                  /usr/lib/systemback/sbsustart
                  /usr/lib/systemback/sbsysupgrade
                  /usr/share/applications/systemback-kde.desktop
                  /usr/share/applications/systemback.desktop
                  /usr/share/systemback/efi-amd64.bootfiles
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_ar_EG.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_ca_ES.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_cs.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_da_DK.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_de.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_en_GB.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_es.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_fi.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_fr.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_gl_ES.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_hu.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_id.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_pt_BR.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_ro.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_ru.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_tr.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_uk.qm
                  /usr/share/systemback/lang/systemback_zh_CN.qm
 Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
 Mounted filesystems: /dev/sdc4 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
                      /dev/sdc1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=007
                      7,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors
                      =remount-ro 0 0
                      /dev/sdc3 /home ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
 System language: it_IT
 Translation: -

mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/sdb5 contiene un file system ext4 con etichetta "SB@"
    last mounted on /.sbsystemcopy on Wed Oct 21 17:04:04 2020
Discarding device blocks: fatto                            
Creazione del file system con 12875520 4k blocchi e 3219456 inode
Etichetta del file system=21cfa7dc-0de7-485f-a111-a56c71c67c6f
Backup del superblocco salvati nei blocchi: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424

Allocating group tables: fatto                            
Scrittura delle tavole degli inode: fatto                            
Creating journal (65536 blocks): fatto
Scrittura delle informazioni dei super-blocchi e dell'accounting del file system: fatto  


 An error occurred while cloning the following file:

 
 /home/p_metheny99/Documenti/PC_ASUS_VivoBook_Pro_15_N580GD_NVIDIA_problemi_vari/EDIT_GRUB_E_INSTALLA_DRIVER_NVIDIA

 Target file:

 
 /.sbsystemcopy/home/p_metheny99/Documenti/PC_ASUS_VivoBook_Pro_15_N580GD_NVIDIA_problemi_vari/EDIT_GRUB_E_INSTALLA_DRIVER_NVIDIA


 /home/p_metheny99/Documenti/PC_ASUS_VivoBook_Pro_15_N580GD_NVIDIA_problemi_vari/EDIT_GRUB_E_INSTALLA_DRIVER_NVIDIA
  d rwx------ - 1000 1000 2083 -

 /home/p_metheny99/Documenti/PC_ASUS_VivoBook_Pro_15_N580GD_NVIDIA_problemi_vari
  d rwx------ - 1000 1000 2083 -
 /home/p_metheny99/Documenti
  d rwx------ - 1000 1000 2083 -
 /home/p_metheny99
  d rwxr-xr-x - 1000 1000 2083 -
 /home
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2083 -


 /.sbsystemcopy/home/p_metheny99/Documenti/PC_ASUS_VivoBook_Pro_15_N580GD_NVIDIA_problemi_vari/EDIT_GRUB_E_INSTALLA_DRIVER_NVIDIA
  f rwx------ 1 0 0 2069 0B

 /.sbsystemcopy/home/p_metheny99/Documenti/PC_ASUS_VivoBook_Pro_15_N580GD_NVIDIA_problemi_vari
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2069 -
 /.sbsystemcopy/home/p_metheny99/Documenti
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2069 -
 /.sbsystemcopy/home/p_metheny99
  d rwxr-xr-x - 1000 1000 2069 -
 /.sbsystemcopy/home
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2069 -
 /.sbsystemcopy
  d rwxr-xr-x - 0 0 2069 -

 Errno: 22
```

The copy of all files within /home dir can be done using normal copy / paste from file manager, but not using systemback copy option that includes userdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happen only when you want to copy your *system+home data* to the new media.
In that case even if you have the correct permissions to allow the copy in all your dirs and files you will get the system copy aborted with Errno: 22.

The issue can be bypassed with unmarking the option:     **Copy user data files**

[image]

In this way it is possible to copy correctly your system without home data toward your new media without get Errno: 22.

Only after you have copied your system with systemback, then it is possible to copy aside with your file manager the whole content of /home toward the new copied system.